# Signing S/MIME with Mimekit (Certicate from store)

Tags: c#, .net-core, mimekit

I want to sign a mime Body with an certificate which is in Windows certmanager store. Same cert works fine to sign Messages with some mailagents (e.g. Outlook, TBird).

I'm loading the certificate  into "store"
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

and with
    X509Certificate2Collection signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, certName, false);

```
 I get the right certificate into signingCert.


 using (var ctx = new TemporarySecureMimeContext())
        {                
            var cert2 = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);
            CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert2);
            ctx.Import(cert2);
            mimeMessage.Body = ApplicationPkcs7Mime.Sign(ctx, signer, DigestAlgorithm.Sha1, body);

        }
```

Problem is (as far as I can see) that CmsSigner expects two Parameters and not one as described. In latest nuget package CmsSigner expects a key as the second Parameter but how do I get the key from the store?

Any hints appreciated… TIA

Comment: Does it have to be BC? Is it just PKCS7/CMS or does it have to be S/MIME? Specifically, any BC code typically exports the private keys to memory, whereas native .net code can interop with CNG (what this means is that BC only works if private key is marked 'exportable' in the certificate store and usually not at all with smartcards).

What if you try `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms` class?

Comment: Should be S/MIME I should also say that I'm a newbie to cryptography and I'll try only sign an outgoing mail from a Web-App with MimeKit

Answer (score 1):

Starting with MimeKit v2.4, the netstandard2.0 API for CmsSigner will be identical to the .NETFramework4.x API, allowing you to create a CmsSigner by passing it an X509Certificate2 without the need to convert it into a BouncyCastle certificate and without needing to convert the X509Certificate2's PrivateKey into a BouncyCastle AsymmetricKeyParameter.

```
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner (certificate2);
```

However, it should be noted that this may or may not work depending on whether or not the private key can be exported.

Comment: WindowsSecureMimeContext Class does not exists. I found an Example but there are many Errors …  I was Looking the last seven days to find an running example but give up  I was ending up everytime in creating a suitable WindowsSecureMimeContext Class. (I know that it can't be that much but I'm on C# since four weeks now and in my age (50) it takes a Little longer to learn ;-) TIA

Comment: The Certificate is marked as exportable. I have to learn more About certificates but I didn't understand why it must be exportable. When it is in Windows store it is readable for all applications with access to that store, right? With "exportable" I think it meant it can be "exported"  to another machine but that is Maybe wrong. Are there any good resources to learn about certifcate handling in Windows?

Comment: If WindowsSecureMimeContext is not available, then it means you are using .NET Core presumably, because it only exists as part of .NET 4.5, 4.6, and 4.7. Since the certificate is exportable, just use the CmsSigner approach I provided in my answer. Exportable doesn't necessarily mean "export to another system", it just means "make the private key usable by software other than core Windows APIs" which is needed because BouncyCastle doesn't use the core Windows APIs to sign/encrypt/etc.

Comment: Thank for clearifying what "exportable" means. That helped me to understand it. Yep, I'm on net Core as tagged in my Question.  I've read in other examples that others written their own WindowsSecureMimeContext Class but can't find the Class itself. MimeKit itself is great! Thank you very much.    Thats also the reason why I'm not using TemporarySecureMimeContext instead of WindowsSecureMimeContext class.

Comment: Most people have probably just copied the WindowsSecureMimeContext.cs file from the official MimeKit repo @ https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/Cryptography/WindowsSecureMimeContext.cs (Note: you'll also need to copy the other WindowsSecureMime*.cs files)

Comment: Error CS0122 'Accessing "BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.TryGetEncryptionAlgorithm(AlgorithmIdentifier, out EncryptionAlgorithm)" not possible . FILE Classes\WindowsSecureMimeDigitalSignature.cs 95   (this is Maybe a missing public Constructor)  
Error  CS1929 '"X509Certificate2" missing Definition for "GetPublicKeyAlgorithm", and the override of  "BouncyCastleCertificateExtensions.GetPublicKeyAlgorithm(X509Certificate)" Needs a receipient of type "X509Certificate".  FILE Classes\WindowsSecureMimeDigitalCertificate.cs

Comment: Just copy that method out of BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.cs into WindowsSecureMimeContext.cs. You'll probably have to do the same for some other internal helper methods. Pretty easy stuff.

Comment: ERROR CS0103 The name "GetSecureMimeCapabilitiesAttribute" does not exists in Context FILE Classes\WindowsSecureMimeContext.cs 653

Comment: Just copy these methods into your WindowsSecureMimeContext.cs file.

Comment: I understand now a Little bit better how it works. But after copy some of the Methods from other classes I get more Errors.  One as example is   RealCmsSigner GetRealCmsSigner(CmsSigner signer)
        {
            var certificate = signer.Certificate.AsX509Certificate2();
            certificate.PrivateKey = signer.PrivateKey.AsAsymmetricAlgorithm();
            return GetRealCmsSigner(certificate, signer.DigestAlgorithm);
        }   and AsymmetricKeyParameter has no AsAsymmetricAlgorithm method.

Comment: I’m working on an easier solution that will simplify this for netstandard2.0

Comment: as far I understood net Standard is out? Net Core is the way of the future.  Or was it the Framework only and bot Standard and Core are up to date? There're so may new Things and I was in my earlier existens coding on Sinclair with Assembler. Much more easier today with .NET but all those different languages and Frameworks drives me crazy :-)

Comment: .NETStandard 2.x is the future for libraries. .NET Core App is the future for apps. .NETFramework v4.x is out. .NET Core Apps can use .NETStandard libraries.

Comment: thank you again to clearify that. You helped me that much to find my way in that Jungle.

Comment: Grab MimeKit >= v2.3.2.14 from https://www.myget.org/feed/mimekit/package/nuget/MimeKit and, if you are using MailKit, you'll need to update that as well from https://www.myget.org/feed/mimekit/package/nuget/MailKit to >= v2.3.2.9

Comment: Consider this a preview for MimeKit & MailKit v2.4