# Unable to Sign MIME entity with X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, .net-core, mimekit

I'm trying to sign an encrypted email. This feature stopped working for me upon updating my certificate and I've been trying to figure out why. I was using an old version of MimeKit so I've updated that and switched to a new CmsSigner ctor (found in this question [Signing S/MIME with Mimekit (Certicate from store)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370388/signing-s-mime-with-mimekit-certicate-from-store)) but I'm now getting this exception.

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'RSACng' is currently not supported.
at MimeKit.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithmExtensions.AsAsymmetricKeyParameter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
at MimeKit.Cryptography.CmsSigner..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate)
```

That's a clear enough error message, what I need a hand with is determining if there's a way to get this certificate to work with the CmsSigner, or if I get a new certificate, what options does it need to support to be used to sign an encrypted email?

```
private static MimeEntity Sign( MimeEntity content, X509Certificate2 signCert ) {

    using ( var mimeContext = new TemporarySecureMimeContext() ) {

        //var signer = new CmsSigner(
        //    DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate( signCert ),
        //    DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair( signCert.PrivateKey ).Private );
                
        var signer = new CmsSigner( signCert );

        signer.DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha1;

        return MultipartSigned.Create( mimeContext, signer, content );
    }
}
```

Comment: S/MIME is effectively broken because offline certificate authenticity doesn't work. Consider using PGP format instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The recipient only accepts S/MIME and unfortunately it's non-negotiable.